# How to handle multiple scenarios within an htaccess, including blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog, force www, force ssl, and url redirects?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do a few things with an htaccess file on my host.

1. Force WWW
2. Force SSL
3. Redirect blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog (blog was formerly on tumblr)
4. Redirect individual old posts on blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog

Currently I've satisfied 1-3, but I can't figure out how to satisfy 4. I can't seem to test or validate for this either. I've tried using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but I can't get it to validate correctly. I also feel like I could be doing these things more efficiently within my htaccess. Any help satisfying 4 would be much appreciated or doing this smarter would be much appreciated.

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Force WWW without forcing certain incoming subdomains to have a WWW (this should handle forcing SSL as well, but I've found I need the other Force SSL rule to make sure that it happens)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Send requests to blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/blog [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.domain.com/404

# For certain query parameters, redirect to support page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/support? [R=301,L]

# Tumblr to Wordpress Redirects
Redirect 301 /post/91531634276/blog-title https://www.domain.com/blog/blog-title/
Redirect 301 /post/45441292642/blog-title-2 https://www.domain.com/blog/blog-title-2/
Redirect 301 /post/46492436919/blog-title-3 https://www.domain.com/blog/blog-title-3/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` is `mod_alias` directive that should not be mixed with `mod_rewrite`. Place these rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/\d+/([^/]+)/?$ https://www.domain.com/blog/$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I have about 70 of these specific posts to redirect (I just didn't include them for brevity). Is it possible to handle all the redirects with a bulk rule?

Comment: This is an incredible answer. Thank you!